# Copy files from USB flash drive on insert

Tags: usb-flash-drive, automation

Is there a way to automatically (on insert) copy all files from specific folder on USB stick to computer's Documents/metafiles/{TODAY_DATE_HERE}/ ?

P.S. I can't use autorun.inf on USB drive as stick's content is generated automatically by software on another computer and I can't modify it's behaviour.

Comment: Is there a specific OS you are trying to accomplish this on?

Comment: It's for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my question myself. It can be accomplished with AutoIt.
Example can be found [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/42402-detecting-usb-drive-insertion/page__view__findpost__p__316005)